# How to find matching values in a dictionary and get a certain output? Pyhton

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and with some items, see here:

```
elements = {
    1: Element(1, nodes[1], nodes[2]),
    2: Element(2, nodes[2], nodes[3]),
    3: Element(3, nodes[3], nodes[4]),
    4: Element(4, nodes[3], nodes[5]),
}
```

The first value in the dictionary resembles the element number.

I want to find the elements for certain nodes.

For example: I want to find all elements containing node number 3, how can I iterate through the dict and find these elements? I had a for loop in mind, but don't know how to get the certain elements.

Comment: For that you will need to provide us the code for the "Element" class

Comment: Just this:def __init__(self, id, node1, node2):
        self.id = id
        self.node1 = node1
        self.node2 = node2

Comment: Also, what kinda of data does the "nodes" array store?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the nodes array stores Objects of the Element class, we can use this list comprehension:

```
result = [i or i in elements if (i.node1.id==3 or i.node2.id==3)]
```